# Can ng-repeat modify the index of an internal collection during reorder

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have an array of objects:

```
$scope.widgets = [{
    col: 0,
    name: "Tile 1"
}, {
    col: 1,
    name: "Tile 2"
}, {
    col: 2,
    name: "Tile 3"
}];
```

Each object is represented as a widget within a grid. For every iteration of ng-repeat, a new widget is created in its respective position(col,row):

```
    <li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
```

What I am finding is that objects in the array change their properties accordingly in terms of position(col/row) via 2 way binding when reordered, but their index do not reflect the change. For example, if the user swapped tiles 1(index 0) and 2(index 1), the properties would be updated, but the objects never swap positions in the array.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RobbyChaps/xg8m00a8/23/embedded/result/) is my fiddle that demonstrates the properties ‘row’ and ‘col’ changing as you move a tile around the grid, but the index never changes. Is it possible to reorder the collection based on the current position of the ng-repeats item?

Example:
User drags tile 2 to tile ones position. Tile two should now become index 0 and tile 1 should now be index 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic solution is that you need to define a callback that will sort the `$scope.widgets` array whenever you have stopped dragging one of them.

I have [forked your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/e0a4653d/) with the full solution, but here are the highlights:

#### Specify the drag callback

Add the following key to your gridster options:

```
draggable: {
    enabled: true,
    stop: function (event, $element, widget) {
        sortWidgets();
    }
}
```

#### Write the sorting code

If you are using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [lodash](http://lodash.com), you can use the `.sortBy()` function to do this pretty easily. Or, you can do it in native JS as well like so:

```
function sortWidgets() {
    $scope.widgets.sort(function (widget1, widget2) {
        return position(widget1) - position(widget2);
    });
}

function position(widget) {
    return (widget.row || 0) * $scope.gridConfig.columns + widget.col;
}
```

#### Use track by for `ng-repeat`

Assuming that your actual widgets are more complicated, I recommend you add a `track by` expression to `ng-repeat` so that it will reuse the same DOM node for the widget *after* the sort as the one it used *before* the sort. You may as well add in this small performance optimisation now, rather than waiting until things get slow.